# Dronekit Python didn't go to specific location

Tags: python, dronekit-python, dronekit, mavlink

I have problem about Dronekit on Python

My project about receive GPS Location from Android application
and Launch drone flying to that Position, Everything work fine but problem is Drone can takeoff but drone didn't go to that Location(Testing 10+ times work only 1 time)

Here is my code (I think problem is GlobalRelative)

```
 # Import DroneKit-Python
from dronekit import connect, VehicleMode, LocationGlobalRelative
import time
import urllib2
import simplejson
import json
import requests


#Wait for json data
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost:3000/posts")
data = simplejson.load(response)
print(data)
json_string = data[0]["Information"]

gps = json.loads(json_string)
x=gps['lat']
y=gps['lon']
r = requests.delete('http://localhost:3000/posts/1')
# Connect to the Vehicle.
print("Connecting")
vehicle = connect('com4', wait_ready=False, baud=57600)#; vehicle.wait_ready(True, timeout=300)
print("Connected")
# Get some vehicle attributes (state)
print "Get some vehicle attribute values:"
print " GPS: %s" % vehicle.gps_0
print " Battery: %s" % vehicle.battery
print " Last Heartbeat: %s" % vehicle.last_heartbeat
print " Is Armable?: %s" % vehicle.is_armable
print " System status: %s" % vehicle.system_status.state
print " Mode: %s" % vehicle.mode.name    # settable

# Takeoff Function
def arm_and_takeoff(tgt_altitude):
    print("Arming motors")

#   while not vehicle.is_armable:
#       time.sleep(1)

    vehicle.mode = VehicleMode("GUIDED")
    vehicle.armed = True

    print("Takeoff")
    vehicle.simple_takeoff(tgt_altitude)

    # wait reach tgt_altitude
    while True:
        altitude = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.alt

        if altitude >= tgt_altitude -1:
            print("Altitude Reached")
            break

        time.sleep(1)

# Main
arm_and_takeoff(10)

# Speed
vehicle.airspeed = 7

# Go to wp
wp1 = LocationGlobalRelative(x, y, 10)

# Close vehicle object before exiting script

vehicle.mode = VehicleMode("RTL")
vehicle.close()


print("Completed")
```

Alternative, If I can't fix this problem I want to use MissionPlanner( I test on it , and it work) But I want to wait for GPS Location from Phone, and Launch the mission( every thing must automatic ) I have no idea how to bypass MissionPlanner

Answer (score 0):

The line: `wp1 = LocationGlobalRelative(x, y, 10)` only assign wp1 variable with a location coordinate. You can use `vehicle.simple_goto(wp1)`. simple_goto is a built in function in dronekit to command the vehicle to specific coordinate you can read more about it here http://python.dronekit.io/automodule.html?highlight=simple_goto#dronekit.Vehicle.simple_goto